# Delete redis keys that have been inactive for 30 days

Tags: scripting, cron, database

I've installed a web app called `scrumblr` which uses `redis` as a database.

What I am attempting to do is delete all keys that have been inactive for 30 days, or have not been accessed in 30 days.

I ran

```
redis-cli KEYS*
```

Which returns all of the keys, though it does not show a timestamp.

Is there a script or a command I can run each day at a specific time, which would seek out all the inactive keys and delete them?

Answer (score 11):

You may make take the advantage of [OBJECT IDLETIME](http://redis.io/commands/object) command, which returns the number of seconds since the object stored at the specified key is idle (not requested by read or write operations).

Example code as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

redis-cli -p 6379 keys "*" | while read LINE ;
do
val=`redis-cli -p 6379 object idletime $LINE`;
if [ $val -gt $((30 * 24 * 60 * 60)) ];
then
  echo "$LINE";
  # del=`redis-cli -p 6379 del $LINE`;  # be careful with del
  # echo $del;
fi
done;
```

In your situation, you can replace `redis-cli -p 6379` with:

`redis-cli -h redis_host -p redis_port -a redis_password`

Comment: Beware! The script above will delete all recent keys. Use -gt instead of -lt to delete keys that are idle for more than 30 days.

Comment: Thanks @Varun, as you point out, I have change "-lt" to "-gt"

Comment: 6: [: ERR: unexpected operator

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: you can iterate over your keys (the output of `KEYS` - *do not use that command in production!* Use `SCAN` instead), call for each key the `OBJECT IDLETIME` command and delete based on the response.

Longer answer: you can actually change scrumplr's [source](https://github.com/aliasaria/scrumblr) to have Redis automatically expire keys after 30 days. The suspect file appears to be `lib/data/redis.js` and the patch requires simply using the `SET...EX` or `EXPIRE` commands on each key after it is written to (room, board, card).

Comment: Thank you. I'm fairly new to node.js and redis but my job requires it. Could you please help me with the commands?

Comment: Sure - what do you need?